# Show hide login/logout in Zend2 if user is logged in

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

How can i show or hide login/logout link if user is loged in. Should this be done directly in view?

In my onDispatch i see that it is using `$this->getAdminAuthService()->hasIdentity()` to check if user is loged in.

How to use it in view like this?

```
if($this->getAdminAuthService()->hasIdentity()){
   echo "<a href="#">login</a>";
}
else {
   echo "<a href="#">Logout</a>"
}
```

Comment: I think you should set `$this->getAdminAuthService()->hasIdentity()` into a variable at the controller and pass it to view.

Comment: How to do that since i do not have an action specialy for header, instead header is included in onDispatch like this     public function onDispatch(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e) {
        
        $header = new ViewModel();
        $header->setTemplate('layout/header');
        $this->layout()->addChild($header, 'header');

Comment: where is `getAdminAuthService` method?

Comment: i have seen this in my onDispatch function in one of my controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your controller:

```
public function onDispatch(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e)
{       
    $header = new ViewModel(array('login'=>$this->getAdminAuthService()->hasIdentity()));
    $header->setTemplate('layout/header');
    $this->layout()->addChild($header, 'header');
}
```

then :

```
//layout/header.phtml
if($this->login){
   echo "<a href="#">login</a>";
} else {
   echo "<a href="#">Logout</a>"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is this the best way to do this type of stuff or should this be done differently?

Answer (score 1):

A [view helper](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.helpers.html) might be a more self contained solution for this

```
namespace MyModule\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use MyModule\Service\AuthService;

class IsAuthenticated extends AbstractHelper
{
  protected $authService;

  public function __construct(AuthService $authService) {
    $this->authService = $authService;
  }

  public function __invoke()
  {
   return $this->authService->hasIdentity();
  }

}
```

Create a factory in your `module.php`

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
  return array(
   'factories' => array(
     'IsAuthenticated' => factory($sl) {
       $authService = $sl->getServiceLocator()->get('AuthService');
       return new View\Helper\IsAuthenticated($authService);
     },
   ),
  );
}
```

Then you can use this within the view or layout - perhaps with a view partial

```
if ($this->isAuthenticated()) {
  // render the login/logout
  $this->partial('some/view/file', array('foo', 'bar'));
}
```

The plugin could be expanded to proxy to other `AuthService` methods. However I hope this brief example shows how to go about it.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It is nice to know it can be handled like this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version of ZF2 you're using, but 2.2.x ships with a view helper for checking a user's identity from the AuthenticationService out of the box.

```
$this->identity();
```

[View Helper - Identity](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.identity.html)

Comment: Thank for this, it is good to know, but i am using Zend 2.0.6